# How to send and receive message in cross tabs in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, postmessage

I want to open a new window and send message to this window and then receive in another tab. I am doing this but it is not working.

```
if (id > 0) {
            var w = window.open(testurl,"address");
            w.postMessage("ddd", "address");
}
```

new window is open but data is not showing.
Here is another window content.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

    function receiveMessage(event) {
        alert(event.data);


    }
</script>
```

Data is not alert. What is the problem?

Comment: You are trying to post the message before the document you are posting it to has loaded. Use a query string if you want the document to have immediate access to the data.

Comment: Yes i also thought this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`targetOrigin` is not the same as the name of the window you're opening. Origin is the value you get when alerting `document.origin` in the opened window.

This is what you should be passing as the second value to `postMessage`; not the name of the window.